# How can I use a nested loop to loop over a list of .yml files and then loop over a list within each one

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-awx

I have a list of yaml files saved as a variable and within each one is a list named "virtual_servers" I need loop over and perform an Ansible module against.

example of list:

```
listOfFiles: [/config/gtm/file1.yml, /config/gtm/file2.yml, /config/gtm/file3.yml, /config/gtm/file4.yml]
```

example of each file:

```
sever_datacenter: East
server_product: generic-host
server_devices:
  - name: aaptestserver1d
    address: 10.4.5.6
server_health_monitors:
  - /Common/prg_tcp
virtual_servers:
  - virtual_server_name: aaptestserver1d_443
    virtual_server_state: enabled
    virtual_server_port: 443
    virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.6
  - virtual_server_name: aaptestserver2d_443
    virtual_server_state: enabled
    virtual_server_port: 443
    virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.7
```

I have tried playing around with loop, with_items, with_nested, and with_sublelements which seems the most promising but when I try I get an error stating "subelements lookup expects a dictionary".

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements: 
        - "{{ listOfFiles }}"
        - virtual_servers
```

Also apparently using the second item in a with_nested to reference the first doesn't work.

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.1 }}"
      with_nested: 
        - "{{ listOfFiles }}"
        - item.0.virtual_servers
```

What I am expecting here in this example would be for it to print out each item in the "virtual_servers" list:

```
  - virtual_server_name: aaptestserver1d_443
    virtual_server_state: enabled
    virtual_server_port: 443
    virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.6

  - virtual_server_name: aaptestserver2d_443
    virtual_server_state: enabled
    virtual_server_port: 443
    virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of your examples won't work because `listOfFiles` is just a list of filenames. It doesn't contain a `virtual_servers` key, nor do any of its list members. That means an expression like...

```
      with_subelements: 
        - "{{ listOfFiles }}"
        - virtual_servers
```

...is never going to work.

---

One option is to build a list of the *contents* of all your data files. Something like this:

```
- set_fact:
    configs: >-
      {{ configs + [lookup("file", item)|from_yaml] }}
  loop: "{{ listOfFiles }}"
  vars:
    configs: []
```

This creates a list `configs`, the items of which are the contents of the files listed in `listOfFiles`. Using that in a playbook might look like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - listoffiles.yaml

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        configs: >-
          {{ configs + [lookup("file", item)|from_yaml] }}
      loop: "{{ listOfFiles }}"
      vars:
        configs: []

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ configs|subelements('virtual_servers') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.server_datacenter }}/{{ item.1.virtual_server_name }}"
```

Assuming that `listoffiles.yaml` contains:

```
listOfFiles:
  - config/file1.yaml
  - config/file2.yaml
```

And `file1.yaml` contains:

```
server_datacenter: West
server_product: generic-host
server_devices:
  - name: aaptestserver1d
    address: 10.6.5.4
server_health_monitors:
  - /Common/prg_tcp
virtual_servers:
  - virtual_server_name: aaptestserver3d_443
    virtual_server_state: enabled
    virtual_server_port: 443
    virtual_server_ip_address: 10.6.5.4
  - virtual_server_name: aaptestserver4d_443
    virtual_server_state: enabled
    virtual_server_port: 443
    virtual_server_ip_address: 10.7.5.4
```

And `file2.yaml` contains:

```
server_datacenter: East
server_product: generic-host
server_devices:
  - name: aaptestserver1d
    address: 10.4.5.6
server_health_monitors:
  - /Common/prg_tcp
virtual_servers:
  - virtual_server_name: aaptestserver1d_443
    virtual_server_state: enabled
    virtual_server_port: 443
    virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.6
  - virtual_server_name: aaptestserver2d_443
    virtual_server_state: enabled
    virtual_server_port: 443
    virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.7
```

Then running the above playbook produces:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=config/file1.yaml)
ok: [localhost] => (item=config/file2.yaml)

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=West/aaptestserver3d_443) => {
    "msg": {
        "virtual_server_ip_address": "10.6.5.4",
        "virtual_server_name": "aaptestserver3d_443",
        "virtual_server_port": 443,
        "virtual_server_state": "enabled"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=West/aaptestserver4d_443) => {
    "msg": {
        "virtual_server_ip_address": "10.7.5.4",
        "virtual_server_name": "aaptestserver4d_443",
        "virtual_server_port": 443,
        "virtual_server_state": "enabled"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=East/aaptestserver1d_443) => {
    "msg": {
        "virtual_server_ip_address": "10.4.5.6",
        "virtual_server_name": "aaptestserver1d_443",
        "virtual_server_port": 443,
        "virtual_server_state": "enabled"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=East/aaptestserver2d_443) => {
    "msg": {
        "virtual_server_ip_address": "10.4.5.7",
        "virtual_server_name": "aaptestserver2d_443",
        "virtual_server_port": 443,
        "virtual_server_state": "enabled"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

...which is I think what you were after.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I will play around to see if it meets my needs.  I am not familiar with your use of "configs: >-"  What does the greater than and dash do?

Comment: That is a YAML multiline quoting operator; for details, see https://yaml-multiline.info/. The `>` operator gathers up everything into a single line (unlike `|`, which preserves newlines). I use it to avoid issues when I have multiple levels of nested quotes (which isn't particularly an issue here but it's a habit).

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of files' content

```yaml
  listOfData: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for f in listOfFiles %}
    - {{ lookup('file', f)|indent(2) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

Now, you can iterate *listOfData*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ listOfData }}"
        - virtual_servers
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    listOfFiles: [file1.yml, file2.yml, file3.yml]
    listOfData: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for f in listOfFiles %}
      - {{ lookup('file', f)|indent(2) }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ listOfData }}"
        - virtual_servers
```

Given the simplified data

```yaml
shell> cat files/file1.yml 
sever_datacenter: East
virtual_servers:
  - virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.1
    virtual_server_state: enabled
  - virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.2
    virtual_server_state: enabled
shell> cat files/file2.yml 
sever_datacenter: East
virtual_servers:
  - virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.3
    virtual_server_state: enabled
  - virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.4
    virtual_server_state: enabled
shell> cat files/file3.yml 
sever_datacenter: East
virtual_servers:
  - virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.5
    virtual_server_state: enabled
  - virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.6
    virtual_server_state: enabled
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

  ...

  msg:
    virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.1
    virtual_server_state: enabled
  msg:
    virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.2
    virtual_server_state: enabled
  msg:
    virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.3
    virtual_server_state: enabled
  msg:
    virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.4
    virtual_server_state: enabled
  msg:
    virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.5
    virtual_server_state: enabled
  msg:
    virtual_server_ip_address: 10.4.5.6
    virtual_server_state: enabled
```